# H2 slow query with in clause does not use indexes

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, h2

I have embedded db with in memory config:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;LOCK_TIMEOUT=4000
```

I have following query what is constructed with hibernate criteria api, when I execute it executes forever, and also it locks all h2 operation i can't read and write.

Largest table is priceline has 18 000 records. It seems for some reason fields that are used in `where` clause do not use my indexes (I have non unique indexes for all fields used for querying, ids have unique indexes)

PLAN

```
SELECT
   * 
FROM PUBLIC.EVENTS EVENT0_
    /* PUBLIC.EVENT_SPORTID_INDX: SPORTID IN(227, 239, 240) */
    /* WHERE EVENT0_.SPORTID IN(227, 239, 240)
    */
    /* scanCount: 137 */
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUBLIC.MARKETS MARKETS1_
    /* PUBLIC.FK7ODW956QJK1DITHJORMVBIV3Q_INDEX_5: EVENTID = EVENT0_.ID */
    ON EVENT0_.ID = MARKETS1_.EVENTID
    /* scanCount: 3230 */
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUBLIC.OUTCOMES OUTCOMES2_
    /* PUBLIC.FK2UJCQIHU8G4B8BQY4JEEY8Y8V_INDEX_3: MARKETID = MARKETS1_.ID */
    ON MARKETS1_.ID = OUTCOMES2_.MARKETID
    /* scanCount: 20599 */
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUBLIC.PRICELINES PRICELINES3_
    /* PUBLIC.FK6PK92YV9ASVTBBIF95R5UWU9N_INDEX_C: OUTCOMEID = OUTCOMES2_.ID */
    ON OUTCOMES2_.ID = PRICELINES3_.OUTCOMEID
    /* scanCount: 36140 */
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUBLIC.OUTCOME_DESCRIPTIONS OUTCOMEDES4_
    /* PUBLIC.FK9AMHE7T653TOKDBK97HK31D4Q_INDEX_7: OUTCOMEID = OUTCOMES2_.ID */
    ON OUTCOMES2_.ID = OUTCOMEDES4_.OUTCOMEID
    /* scanCount: 260890 */
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUBLIC.MARKET_DESCRIPTIONS MARKETDESC5_
    /* PUBLIC.FK5X545B89XD3COBCN7EFM04RJC_INDEX_A: MARKETID = MARKETS1_.ID */
    ON MARKETS1_.ID = MARKETDESC5_.MARKETID
    /* scanCount: 3391570 */
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUBLIC.MARKETFILTER_MAPPING FILTERS6_
    /* PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_E: EVENTID = EVENT0_.ID */
    ON EVENT0_.ID = FILTERS6_.EVENTID
    /* scanCount: 26881816 */
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUBLIC.MARKET_FILTERS MARKETFILT7_
    /* PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_9: ID = FILTERS6_.MARKETFILTERID */
    ON FILTERS6_.MARKETFILTERID = MARKETFILT7_.ID
    /* scanCount: 47472776 */
LEFT OUTER JOIN PUBLIC.EVENT_DESCRIPTIONS EVENTDESCR8_
    /* PUBLIC.FKOR6YEH06F2B0D389L2SYV1LX8_INDEX_F: EVENTID = EVENT0_.ID */
    ON EVENT0_.ID = EVENTDESCR8_.EVENTID
    /* scanCount: 332363850 */
WHERE (OUTCOMEDES4_.LOCALE = 'en-GB')
    AND ((MARKETDESC5_.LOCALE = 'en-GB')
    AND ((EVENTDESCR8_.LOCALE = 'en-GB')
    AND ((MARKETFILT7_.PERIODID IN(209, 113, 100))
    AND ((MARKETS1_.PERIODID IN(209, 113, 100))
    AND ((MARKETFILT7_.MARKETTYPEID IN(3059, 68, 1))
    AND ((MARKETS1_.TYPEID IN(3059, 68, 1))
    AND ((EVENT0_.SPORTID IN(227, 239, 240))
    AND (PRICELINES3_.PRICELINEID = 2))))))))
ORDER BY 10 DESC
(1 row, 152204 ms)
```

Comment: well on hsqldb it works and takes 40ms)